# Measuring various aspects of code

Tags: python, code-analysis, code-metrics

Is there a tool that is able to measure the frequency of function calls in a project and counts other aspects (for statistics purposes) of Python code?

thank you

Comment: What aspects? Whether the most significant bit is set in the seventh bytecode instruction of the code object the function was compiled to?

Comment: @delnan The aspects should relate to the static code (not in execution), frequency of function calls, average lengths of functions. These are enough for me, but I can image there could be various other properties of code - you were creative but I would probably not utilize your suggestion.

Comment: Sounds like OP wants just static anlayses of code metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do static code analysis. How many *locations* in your code
call a function.

This is very hard to do in dynamic languages like python, because there are so many
ways functions may be called otherwise than by proper name, and even the python bytecode compiler
won't know always which function is going to be called in a place, and it may even change
during execution. And there's standard OO polymorphism too.

Consider:

```
def doublefx(f, x):
    return f(x)*2

print doublefx(math.sqrt, 9)  # 6 

f = stdin.readline()
print doublefx(getattr(math, f), 9)  # ?
```

No way any static analyses tool will find out which functions in math.* are going to
be called by this code. Even the first example would be very hard to reason about,
the second is impossible.

The following tool does some static analysis regarding complexity.

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymetrics/

Other analysis tools like PyLint and PyChecker rather focus on style and probable
errors.

Comment: Actually it's text analysis, because if the function is called in a for loop I don't want to count it many times. I want to only count "function call occurences in text". If there is not tool, I will have to try regular expressions, but I think that special cases you showed should be manageable too.

Comment: It seems that pymetrics is best I can find now. I see in the source code that there is a type of token FCNNAME, so I will probably be able to adjust the code and insert the various FCN_NAMEs to dictionary and count occurences. I will have to look at it in detail later. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The Python profiler should provide you with quite a bit of information:

```
python -m cProfile -o fooprof myscript.py
```

You load the results using a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pstats
p = pstats.Stats('fooprof')
p.strip_dirs().sort_stats(-1).print_stats()
```

Alternatively, if you do not specify `-o fooprof` the results are printed to stdout.

See the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

I'm not sure what "other aspects" you are wanting to count, but this will determine how *many* times the function is called.  If you are interested in the "frequency" of calls, then you can find the average frequency as a function of total execution time and the number of times the function was called.  For example:

Suppose `foo()` was called 100 times in 10 seconds.  The average frequency of calls is then 10/second.

Comment: frequency of static source code (not in execution) is sufficient, but can I use it on whole project (directory and all subdirectories)?

Comment: It seems that `cProfile` options is working with code in execution because it can't connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but it looks like [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual) might be a good place to start.  (Note that of the three profilers mentioned on that page, one (hotshot) is experimental and not well-supported, one (profile) "adds significant overhead to profiled programs", and the last is cProfile, so probably go with that.)  Links to the source code for `profile.py` and `pstats.py` are provided at the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you but I'm probably not looking a profiler, I'm interested only in source code statistics (not the execution statistics)

Comment: It looks to me like cProfile records the name (among other things) of each function called, and pstats has some methods to access that kind of information.  If you don't want stats about how your code actually runs and just what it looks like, then do `cat * | grep myfunc(.*?)` in your code directory to get each line with a call to `myfunc`.  Then count them?  Note that this command is for Linux only.